# adjustable IGBT current?

Tags: current-measurement, current-limiting, igbt

Goodmorning all,

Here my very first question so I may be asking something that is may be already answerd but I couldn't find,

My question is : How is current limiting achieved in modern IGBT based welding equipment? I do have a DC TIG welder myself and I am just curious how to achieve a max current setting from let's say a very wide range between 5-180 Amps?

I have googled quite a lot but I can't find anything that is helping me understanding this aspect of power electronics

The only thing that gets close to it is the  [CS8312](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/CS8312-D.PDF) that controls the gate of the IGBT for a specific max current through the IGBT.

Any help suggestion is appriciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an inductive load and PWM.

IGBT's are optimised to be Discrete ON or OFF devices and do not have a linear/active region like MOSFET's and BJT's.

The CS8312 shows an example setup with an inductive load and a sense resistor.

This particular chip works by increasing the threshold by 45%

> Changing the CLI pin from a logic low to a logic high increases the
>   FLAG turn on voltage by approximately 45% and the regulation sense
>   voltage by approximately 39% respectively.

Other methods are via simple comparator for hysteresis control or PI controller to then generate a PWM signal that is indirectly used to drive the IGBT

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it means that the effective or dynamic current == (Ton/(Ton+Toff))*Imax? You would also expect more like a square wave Usense I guess?

Comment: not quite for average current as there is the slope to consider. For this topology with the current not in the freewheel path, Yes  Usense would be "square wave" & depending on how much inductance, there should be a slope.  NOTE: it is assumed the freewheel diode is part of the load.

Comment: I_lo  + 0.5*(dI*Ton^2 + dI*Toff^2 )/(Ton + Toff) ...  Where I_lo = low current, dI is the change in I (T_hi - Tlo)

Comment: The inductance load causes also the ramp up slope's angle of the upgoing Load current when the IGBT is on and also the ramp down angle/slope of the receding Load current or to be more precise : the current through the load which has a clear inductance component